# Javascript error when trying to create a calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm brand new to javascript and php and having a slight problem.

I'm trying to create a php calendar that interacts with mysql database and have been trying to write some javascript to add events to the calendar.

My events are being brought from the mysql database but whenever I click to add an event to the calendar I get an error in the console saying "uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" which appears to be caused by these lines in the code:

```
         var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
         var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

My code is below, console log 'testing function success' is not being displayed. Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//get current date 
 var date = new Date();
 var d = date.getDate();
 var m = date.getMonth();
 var y = date.getFullYear();


     var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     theme:true,
     weekNumbers: true,
     //allow a 'more' option if too many events.
     eventLimit: true,  
      //enables agenda view 
     header:{
            left:'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
         }, 

     events: 'event.php',

     selectable: true,
     selectHelper: true, 
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        console.log('testing function 1');
         var title = prompt('Event Title:');
         if (title) {
         var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
         var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
         $.ajax({
         url: 'eventadd.php',
         data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end ,
         type: "POST",
         success: function(json) {
         console.log('testing function success');
         alert('OK');
         }
         });
         calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
         {
         title: title,
         start: start,
         end: end,
         allDay: allDay
         },
         true // make the event "stick"
         );
         }
         calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },








     });

             });
```

Comment: And what random calendar are you using?

Comment: looks like full calendar...

Comment: I'm using full calendar, a jquery plugin

Comment: Put exception handling in your code http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp. This will get you to the line number that is throwing the exception. Then we can work on solving that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of lines

```
    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

use (take care not to redefine local varialbes  start, end, which  are params of the function, also use Moment's format function according to: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/  as recommended by the fullCalendar v2 code migration):

```
    var sfmated = start.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    var efmated = end.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

a working jsfiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xv5n1wod/12/